# Export content and images from Umbraco to JSON or XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, export, umbraco

Is there a simple way of exporting everything from at node and below (so recursive) in Umbraco? Say i want to export all 'About us' items (ID 555 root), and the images/media used in these items? I just need to export them to a simple format like JSON or XML, and have the media saved on the local disk.

Any ideas or snippets?

PS: It is an older Umbraco solution - Umbraco 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the tables `umbracoNode` (nodes, node hierarchy) and `cmsContentXml` ([cache](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/developers/api-questions/15465-Regenerating-cmsContentXml-table)). Be sure the cache is up-to-date (see comments in link).

I'd iterate over the node tree and write the contents of the `xml` column to a file.

Depending on how you link media, you either have a media property, or need to parse HTML inside the XML. Bear in mind that all the media in Umbraco should reside under `~/Media` anyway.